# Fill textboxes sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I have 5 textboxes (With pre-populated data) representing address lines 1,2,...5 respectively. The requirement is to check if TEXTBOX 1 is empty, then shift data from textbox 2 to 1, textbox 3 to 2 and so, on. This is to make sure there aren't any empty textboxes in between the sequential textboxes. How do I achieve it in Jquery? If all textboxes are empty, I will show required field error.

Here I am just trying to save data in a variable.

```
 custData.CustAddr1 = $("#txtCustAddr1" + value).val().trim() == "" ? $("#txtCustAddr2" + value).val() : $("#txtCustAddr1" + value).val();
```

In the above code I need to check all the 5 textboxes, If txtbox1 is empty, use data from textbox 2, else from 3 else 4 else 5.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Code please...?

Comment: imho, the code in this question is not need, it's fine as just algorithmical question.

Comment: Ya.. exactly @dfsq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Vanilla JavaScript (jQuery solution below)

Here is a solution that does not use jQuery. It uses linear time and does not update textbox values when this is not needed, so it is no problem to call this often.

The idea on a high level is to keep track of which is the first empty textbox and, while looping over all textboxes, move textbox values to this empty one as we encounter them.

You can display an error if at the end of this function, the first empty textbox is still the first one (`firstEmpty === 0` in the below demo code).

```js
function enforceSequential(selector) {
  var firstEmpty = -1, current = -1,
      textboxes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for (let textbox of textboxes) {
    current++;
    if (textbox.value === '') {
      if (firstEmpty < 0) {
        firstEmpty = current;
      }
    } else if (firstEmpty >= 0) {
      textboxes[firstEmpty].value = textbox.value;
      textbox.value = '';
      firstEmpty++;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click', () => enforceSequential('.box'));
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="box" value="foo" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="bar" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="baz" />
<button id="run">Run script</button>
```

#### jQuery variant

Of course, if you want to use jQuery, you can.

```js
function enforceSequential(selector) {
  var firstEmpty = -1,
      textboxes = $(selector);
  textboxes.each((current, textbox) => {
    textbox = $(textbox);
    if (textbox.val() === '') {
      if (firstEmpty < 0) {
        firstEmpty = current;
      }
    } else if (firstEmpty >= 0) {
      textboxes.eq(firstEmpty).val(textbox.val());
      textbox.val('');
      firstEmpty++;
    }
  });
}

$('#run').on('click', () => enforceSequential('.box'));
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="box" value="foo" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="bar" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="" />
<input type="text" class="box" value="baz" />
<button id="run">Run script</button>
```

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best method would be :

- Get all textboxes values that are not empty as a JS array
- If array is empty, display your error
- Else, empty textboxes values
- Then fill textboxes (in correct order) with array values

Comment: that would probably be fine, or you could just check if txtbox[index] is empty then move from txtbox[index+1] and loop index. Then you can vary the number of textboxes without changing code.

Comment: Sure, but you would need to loop o(n²). If the first two textboxes are empty, that would put an empty value in #1. You will need to loop another time form 0 to <4, then 0 to <3 etc.

Comment: Plus, with the upper algorithm then is no place when you would need to hard code the number of textboxes

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution. But loop solution is probably more interesting and tricky.

Comment: This uses a lot of memory to duplicate all textbox values and unnecessarily updates all textbox values when there are no empty textboxes in between filled ones. It also loops over all textboxes twice, while looping once is enough. Of course, these remarks won't be a concern in practice at all, when there are only 5 textboxes. Anyway, I provided an answer that does address these concerns.

Comment: To address the comments: o(n2) whatever has no impact when it's only a handful of textboxes. You're correct about needing to handle two empty inputs in a row but would still only need one loop.  If there's lots/content is large then the memory impact of loading them all would out-weight the time processing. You wouldn't need to hardcode the max as it would be `$(".textbox").length`